# Strange for loop / array problem in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, for-loop, 3-tier

This is my first question here on StackOverflow, and quite frankly I'm fairly new to PHP. Just to give you a brief heads-up ;)

I'm building an OOP-based website, in a 3-tier architecture. In my data abstraction layer, I have an object I called DbAdapter, which contains all functions necessary to communicate with the database. One of these functions is the one below: read($sql), which takes an SQL query and stores the result in a two-dimensional array.

For this, it uses two nested for-loops (one for the rows and one for the columns per row). And while the iterator $i increments as usual, somehow the last element of the array is overwritten.

I have absolutely no idea how this is possible, so the mistake I made *must* be extremely stupid.

Anyone care to help out a newbie?

Thanks in advance, Sam

```
public $loadedRows;
public function read($sql)
{
    if ($this->connect())
    {
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if ($result)
        {
            $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            $totalFields = mysql_num_fields($result);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRows; $i++)
            {
                for ($j = 0; $j < $totalFields; $j++)
                {
                    $fieldName = mysql_field_name($result, $j);
                    $loadedFields["$fieldName"] = mysql_result($result, $i, $fieldName);
                }

                $this->loadedRows[i] = $loadedFields;
            }

            $this->closeConnection();
            return $this->loadedRows;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the following function: http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php It's a built in function that does what you're doing. :)

Comment: People should really start to appreciate PDO. A little `PDOStatement->fetchAll` absoletes your whole code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just forgot $ before i `$this->loadedRows[$i]`

and this code should be way shorter:

```
public function read($sql)
{
    $a = array();
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $a[]=$row;
    }
    return $a;
}
```

That's ALL.

and to catch these errors yourself, you should set error reporting level to `E_ALL`
to do that you can add this line

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in your config file.
It will tell PHP to watch such mistakes (using undefined constant i in this case) and notify you

Comment: Unbelievable! I knew my error had to be stupid. And thanks a lot for the quick reply and the coding advice! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you can't just do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    $this->loadedRows[] = $row;
}
```

In place of both your loops? Fetching fieldnames/values individually like this is hideously slow compared to just fetching a associative row which has the fieldname/values in it already.

Personally, I prefer eating a bowlful of cheerios, rather than individually pulling one from a box, putting it in the bowl, pouring on a drop of milk, eating it, then going back to the box for another one.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the missing `$` before `i` here is your culprit:

```
           $this->loadedRows[i] = $loadedFields;
```

Comment: @Sam, no worries. Good luck ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use PDO instead of these old mysql functions.
[PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) does what you need.